# I want to make sure that the user enters unique values every time when asked to enter value

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, input

```
cout<<"Enter numbers from 0 to 8 in any order"<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<=8;i++){
    cout<< "Input "<<i<<endl;
    cin>>index[i];
 }
```

So here's a snippet of the code. What condition do I need to apply to prevent the the user from entering the same value more than once? I am aware that `if` and `else` or `switch` can be user but how do I compare previous inputs with the new one?

anything besides `if(index[1]==index[2]||index[3]==index[4]||.... )` ?

Comment: A naive solution would be to scan the `index` array from start until a count `i` after each input and compare the new value to each value in the array upto that point.

Comment: And how exactly would I be able to do that in C++?

Comment: Please check my answer below. Here's a [running example](https://ideone.com/A6mupO)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things that you'd have to do to accomplish. The `do-while` loop seems to be promising in the scenario you have because you have to keep taking inputs until you have 8 unique numbers between 0 to 8.

#### Steps/Algorithm:

1. Allocate the required memory for `index` which is an `int[]`, say `int index[8]` for now.
2. Have a variable to store the counter for the number of values successfully inserted into the array `index`.
3. Run a `do-while` loop where the while condition is the `counter < 8`
4. Inside the `do` block, assign a temporary `int` to store the input from the user. lets call it `int temporary_input; cin>>temporary_input;`
5. Sanity check if the given input is `>= 0 && <= 8`
6. Now scan the `index[]` from `0 to counter`, use a function that returns `int` or `boolean` response for the same based on the condition `if the number already exists`
7. If the number doesn't exist then assign it to `index[counter]` and increment `counter`

Here's a program that might be helpful

```
// arr : integer array of the values
// l   : current length of the integer array
// n   : the number that needs to be checked for existence
int check_input(int *arr, int l, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<l ; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == n) {
            // if number already exists; return true (1)
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Main
int main() {
    cout << "Enter numbers from 0 to 8 in any order"<<endl;
    // Initialize required variables to store the inputs and counter.
    int index[8];
    int i=0;
    // Repeat until the size is 8. (0-7 = 8 values)
    do {
        int temporary_input;
        cin>>temporary_input;
        // Check if input is less than equal to 8 or greater than equal to 1
        if (temporary_input >= 1 && temporary_input <= 8) {
            // Check if the number given as input already exists
            if (check_input(index, i, temporary_input) == 0) {
                // if number doesn't exist, assign it to index
                index[i] = temporary_input;
                i++;
            }   
        }
    } while (i < 8);

    // Print values
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        cout<<index[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
2 2 1 8 3 4 7 7 5 6 5 4
```

Sample output:

```
Enter numbers from 0 to 8 in any order
2 1 8 3 4 7 5 6
```

Here's a [running example](https://ideone.com/A6mupO)